# Escaping Problem in bash using isql

Tags: bash, isql

I am currently working on a little backup script from some firebird databases and I've come up with a weird escaping problem that I don't seem to be able to solve. Here's the thing in my script I create a variable called sqllog in which I would like to put the output of a chain of commands, here it is.

```
sqllog=`echo "SELECT * FROM RDB\$DATABASE;" | isql -u SYSDBA -pass mypasswd localhost:mydatabase | tail -n 2 | head -n 1 | wc -l`
```

if I try to execute this in shell I get the following error

```
Statement failed, SQLCODE = -204

Dynamic SQL Error
-SQL error code = -204
-Table unknown
-RDB
-At line 1, column 15.
```

Table unknown RDB means it didn't take my try to escape the $.

thx for any help :)

Comment: in fact the `` signs are arround the statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try with

```
sqllog=`echo 'SELECT * FROM RDB\$DATABASE;' | isql -u SYSDBA -pass mypasswd localhost:mydatabase | tail -n 2 | head -n 1 | wc -l`
```

Comment: awesome that work I just replaced the " quotes with ' quotes :) 

thx for everyone helping me :)

Answer (score 0):

The line :

```
sql=$(echo "SELECT * FROM RDB\$DATABASE;")
```

will set sql to

```
SELECT * FROM RDB$DATABASE;
```

I suppose that it is what you want i.e. that the isql command will interpret the `$DATABASE` variable.

(If not and DATABASE is a shell variable, then you just have to use `sql=$(echo "SELECT * FROM RDB$DATABASE;")`

What did isql expect ? Give me more details ...